# Calculate with sequences from OEIS

Tags: sequences-and-series, online-resources, wolfram-alpha

Is there any easy way to do calculations with sequences from OEIS online? For example
I would like to input something like:

```
(A007620(n+1) / 2 )  + A000027(n)
```

and then get something like

```
4, 8, 12, 14, 17, 20, ...
```

I tried Wolfram Alpha which can access the sequences but I did not find any way to calculate with them there.

Comment: I assume you have studied [this already](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40/is-it-possible-to-invoke-the-oeis-from-mathematica)!

Comment: @DroneScientist wow, no I was not aware of this

Comment: @DroneScientist feel free to post this as an answer to collect the 50 bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is well discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40/is-it-possible-to-invoke-the-oeis-from-mathematica)!

One may write functions in Mathematica that work with OEIS data and some of the answers include functionality that one may build upon.

Answer (score 0):

If I am writing a program to handle the data, I would just copy the first few hundred terms of the series into a txt document and directly access it as an array.